# Jquery/Css Issue #2: Hover Elements triggering unwanted hovering action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Long time ago, I made a question with the concept: Jquery/CSS challenge, where I use Jquery to fill in for CSS place and was given the hover function (because I haven't learned that before, and is now very useful!)  So I copied the code, edited it to my liking to make my homemade 'navigation' buttons made by the span attribute (i know i can use button, but was curious on how it plays here).

So when I begin to test it, I noticed an odd behavior.  After I started my hovering activity on multiple 'same' attributes. My mouse acted weirder when my on hover acts like 'off hover' and when I go away it acted like I was 'on hover'.  I even edited to mouse enter and mouse leave from the jQuery library and I still run into the same issue, HELP!

Here is my sample of code used for the jQuery-Css Project:

```
$(document)
    .ready(
        function() {
            var $span = $("span");
            $span
                .css(
                    {
                        "background-color" : "#eef"
                    }
                )
                .hover(
                    function (){
                        $(this)
                            .css(
                                {
                                    "background-color" : "#ddf"
                                }
                            )
                        ;
                    },
                    function () {
                        $(this)
                            .css(
                                {
                                    "background-color" : "#eef"
                                }
                            )
                        ;
                    }
                )
            ;       
        }
    )
;
```

Then the appropriate HTML coding used for this scenario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Jquery Test Page.</title>
        <!--[if lte IE 7]>
            <style>
                .content { 
                    margin-right: -1px;
                } /* this 1px negative margin can be placed on any of the columns in this layout with the same corrective effect. */
                ul.nav a { 
                    zoom: 1;
                }  /* the zoom property gives IE the hasLayout trigger it needs to correct extra whiltespace between the links */
            </style>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="menu">
            <span id="a">I am button A</span>
            <span id="b">I am button B</span>
            <span id="c">I am button C</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I do spread my coding out just for easy editing purposes, but I need help with this!  Thank you all for making this a good community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not acting weird. That is happening because you have made two functions there in the hover event. The first one is fired when you hover and the second one when you left the button. If you want only the hover event you can make only one function there

```
$span.css({"background-color" : "#eef"}).hover(function (){
   $(this).css({"background-color" : "blue"});
});
```

And you can use `mouseleave` function in jquery to understand when the user left the button.

> Read this article for better understand
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

Comment: Its nice to have the hover on all elements, but I wanted to run the over event on each of the same attribute, say two or three of those p attributes that only one can be hovered at a time.  the off hover or second function returns the background color to its original state.

Comment: i forgot to specify my bad

Comment: i am not sure if i am understanding what you really want

Comment: Im not great at words, i do appoligize.  When you run the "try it yourself" and add another p attribute.  You will see the same issue I seen, where both p attributes acted in hover.  I wanted to see if there was a way i can make each p attribute hover individually, like one was hovered and the other one remains at rest

Comment: somehow on the try it yourself, i did some more editing, it was simply my poor scripting skills.  Thanks though for your help!  did upvote it

Comment: So you are basically saying if you have two <p>  you want the hover event only to the first one for ex? it is easy all you need is to give an id to it <p id='test'>helllo</p and in jquery you will have $myEl = $('#test');

Comment: Here is a good article for selectors http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp